# What are the possible bad consequences of changing ENV to 'production' in the middle of a test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I wrote a code that needs to be run only in production environment. In my spec/test file, when testing this code, I have to change the ENV variable to 'production' so the code works.

The code:

```
do_something if Rails.env.production?
```

Spec:

```
context "some context" do

  before { Rails.env = 'production' }

  # test something

end
```

My question is: there is a problems with this approache? Other option is to change the code to run when in 'production' OR 'test' environment. Is this "better" in some way? I feel that I should not change the environment in the middle of a test but don't know if this is right and why.

Comment: There is probably a very long list of potential side effects like Rails connecting to the wrong database.

Comment: `do_something` should be isolated so that you can test it regardless of the environment. Even if that means stubbing certain portions.

Comment: A possible very dangerous side effect could be that you run your test against your production database what – depending on your test setup – might lead to truncation of your production database tables...

Comment: I know this isn't what you're asking... But to avoid this in the future (or resolve it here if it's a new project) never use the environment name in the actual code. Instead use settings, which vary per environment. For example, here `if Rails.env.production?` can be `if Settings.something_enabled?` and you can simply stub it for that spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing environments in the middle of your test, create an instance of ActiveSupport:StringInquirer(the class of Rails.env) and use that instead:

```
 class MyClassThatNeedsEnvironment
     def initialize(env)
       @env = env
     end

     def foo
       do_something if @env.production?
     end
 end
```

Test Example:

```
    context "test" do

    let(:my_class_instance) {
        env_as_string = Rails.env.to_s    
MyClassThatNeedsEnvironment.new(ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(env_as_string))

    }

    end

    context "production" do
      let(:my_class_instance) {
        env_as_string = 'production'   

    MyClassThatNeedsEnvironment.new(ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(env_as_string))

    }
    end
```

This carries no side effects and preserves dependency inversion.